# Determine whether a sequence space is normed

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(a_k)$ be a monotonously decreasing sequence of positive numbers with $a_1 =1$ and $a_k\to 0$. Let also $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ diverge.
If $1\leq p<\infty$, show that
$$A := \lbrace (x_k) : x_k\in\mathbb{R},\sup\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k|x_{\pi (k)}|^p<\infty\rbrace$$
is a normed space w.r.t to the supposed norm
$$ \|(x_k)\| :=\sup\limits_\pi\left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k|x_{\pi (k)}|^p\right )^{1/p}$$
where $\pi$ is a substitution of $\mathbb{N}$.

The trouble is verifying the triangle inequality:
$$\|x_k+y_k\|\overset{?}\leq\|x_k\|+\|y_k\|$$
It very much looks like a spot to utilize the Minkowski inequality, however, it's only applicable for finite sums. Is it also true that if Minkowski holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then it also holds in case of a series? (Have not yet touched on trans-finite induction).

Looking further into the matter, it turns out, the space in question is actually said to be a "Lorentz sequence space", however, looking for relevant info on it didn't yield any mention of it being normed, much less of any proof of this being true.

Comment: Minkowski's inequality also holds for infinite series.

Comment: What you have is a subset of something called an $l_p$ space, a type of Banach space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These results are mentioned in (eg) Lindenstrauss/Tzafrir Classical Banach Spaces I - Sequence Spaces: it is simply commented that with this norm the Lorentz sequence space is a Banach space.

Verifying the triangle inequality: $\sup_\pi (\sum a_n |x_{\pi(n)} + y_{\pi(n)}|^p)^{1/p} \leq \sup_\pi (\sum a_n |x_{\pi(n)}|^p)^{1/p} + (\sum a_n |y_{\pi(n)}|^p)^{1/p} $ by Minkowski, which is $\leq \sup_\pi (\sum a_n |x_\pi(n)|^p)^{1/p} + \sup_\sigma (\sum a_n |y_{\pi(n)}|)^{1/p}$, as $\sup a+b \leq \sup a + \sup b$.

Minkowski is applicable in any measure space $L^p(S)$ (see, eg, wikipedia for a proof of this).